# How to update symfony?

Tags: symfony1

It looks like it is a stupid question, but i could not figure how to update symfony to 1.3.
When i follow [the tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/tutorial/1_4/en/upgrade) to update my project, one of the step says "Upgrade symfony to 1.3" which is actually what i am following the tuto for...
Well i guess there is a difference between updating the project and symfony.
But i can not find out how to do this step.
I tried to type the command

```
pear upgrade symfony/symfony-1.3.0
```

which seamed to work (upgrade ok), but when i type

```
php symfony -V
```

it still tells me that i have the 1.2.9 version, and the project:update1.3 does not exist...

I don't really know much about pear, i did this in my root symfony path, is that correct ?
I also copied all files from lib/vendor/symfony before, but it didn't work either.

Someone could help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your project configured to load symfony from? Check your ProjectConfiguration.class.php in the config directory. You'll have to update the version of symfony that it is pointing to.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you very much for your help ! I can't believe it's working !